# Change class attributes parameters dynamically

Tags: c#, nunit

how can i change the attributes parameters dynamically(in run time) in the following code( for TestFixture and TestConfiguration):

```
[
    TestFixture("Setup 1"),
    TestConfiguration("http://spiratest", "rin", "rin", 30, 924, 2577, 
    TestConfigurationAttribute.RunnerName.NUnit)
]
    public  class SampleTestFixture
    {
        protected static int testFixtureState = 1;

        [TestFixtureSetUp]
        public void FixureInit()
        {
            //Set the state to 2
            testFixtureState = 2;
        }

        [SetUp]
        public void Init()
        {
            //Do Nothing
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sample test that asserts a failure
        /// </summary>
        [
        Test,
        TestCase(41681)
        ]
        public void _01_SampleFailure()
        {
            //Verify the state
            Assert.AreEqual (2, testFixtureState, "*Real Error*: State not persisted");

            //Failure Assertion
            Assert.AreEqual (1, 1, "Failed as Expected");
        }   
}
```

i need to change the attributes parameters for TestFixture and TestConfiguration on RunTime.(with no using const parameters)

how can i change it by reflection or annotation?

Comment: You want to change the tests name? Why do you need this? I doubt this is possible because even if you could *change* the values NUnit won´t recognize them as the tests are already created and run.

Comment: i need to change the parameter in the TestFixture instead of "Setup 1"

Comment: i need to change the parameter in the TestFixture instead of "Setup 1" to be a string parameters that will be assign in runtime.

Comment: So what should happen when you change the value of the TestFixture at runtime? Shell all tests be re-run with the new values? Or only those that have not been run so far? Your question makes not much sense.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nunit parameterised TestFixtures with parameters set at runtime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605567/nunit-parameterised-testfixtures-with-parameters-set-at-runtime) ?

Comment: yes all tests in this class should be run with the new value that is being set in runtime . with no need to recompile again .

Comment: Take a look at [TestFixtureSource](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestFixtureSource-Attribute) - that may be what you're after.

Comment: thanks you all. i have another attribute TestConfiguration . how can i change its parameters too?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt what you want is possible. Whenever you have attributes on a class, method or any member those are handled using reflection at any time using `GetCustomAttributes`.

```
// find the fixtures
// ...
// provide the attributes and create the fixture
var newTestInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(SampleTestFixture), theParams)
```

When you call the member with those attributes you provide the information within the attribute to that member or constructor, however the member (or constructor) has *already been called* with the values provided by those attributes. What you want is therefor similar to this:

```
class MyClass {
    int MyInt;
    MyClass(int param)
    {
        MyInt = param;
    }
}
```

So when you *provide* the parameter to the constructor its value is bound to `MyInt`. When you change the attributes value NUnit is **not notified** in any way, so it won´t re-create your test or even modify the already existing one. Both would be harmful. In the first place you would create a completely new test. In the second case you would have to determine which tests *have* already been run and re-run those with the modifed value.

So what should happen when you change the value of the `TestFixture` at runtime? Shell all tests be re-run with the new values? Or only those that have not been run so far?

Comment: all tests should be run with the new value.

Comment: The answer is "it's not possible" - but really he probably has some more meaningful question he should be asking, the reason why he imagines he needs to do this. Whatever it is, dynamically changing the code is probably not the answer. :-)